# How Can I change button text in C# based on a text on Database?

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and I am using windows forms.

[image: screenshot]

As shown in screenshot, I want when form1 loads all buttons' text change based on its name on the database. 
I have already wrote some code which import data from the database but next I want to change each button text according to its name on the database when form1 loads.

please help me how to modify this code to achieve what I want.Thank you

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PCNDVR-TOSH!;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True");

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM button_txt");

        cm.Connection = con;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();


    }
```

Comment: It's pEpEroni, not paparoni. XD

Comment: @ Bujutsu . ao my god you saved my life, if you did not correct me the compiler won't pass this mistake and my program won't work...whatever. we are here to solve bigger issue than silly unintended mistakes. and by the way it is "Pepperoni" NOT  "peperoni" as you said.

Comment: Haha, I was going to say, what an unnecessary comment.

Comment: (the Italian word is "peperoni", so that wasn't a mistake)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    Button targetButton = null;

    switch(row["button_name"].ToString().ToLower())
    {
        case "button1":
            targetButton = myFirstButton;
            break; 
        case "button2":
            targetButton = mySecondButton;
            break; 
        case "button3":
            targetButton = myThirdButton;
            break; 
    }

    targetButton.Text = row["button_txt"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: @ roryap . i tried your code but it did not work it gives error that the ["button1"] is not a column in database and row index should be incremented by 1 to go to next row. it should be like this: myFirstButton.Text = dt.Rows[0]["button_txt"].ToString(); . thank you

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood your db structure.  See my update.

Answer (score 1):

```
//After the connection is closed
DataRow[] dra = dt.Select("button_name = 'button1'");
myFirstButton.Text = dra[0]["button_txt"];

//Alternate way of referencing datarow 
dra = dt.Select("button_name = 'button2'");
mySecondButton.Text = dra[0][1];entries

//Removing the need for the dra[]
myThirdButton.Text = dt.Select("button_name = 'button3'")[0][1];
```